# How to find total working days or total working hours spent?

Tags: sql, presto

I'm seeking help to find the "total working days" and "total working hours" spent between 2 dates; Start_Date and End_Date. So far, I'm only able to find the total hours between 2 dates, excluding the weekends. Then I convert this total hours to days (divide by 24).

Down the road, I will need to incorporate public holidays (such as Thanksgiving, Christmas, etc) to this. In addition, instead of number of working days, how do I find total number of working hours (assume working hours is 8am to 5pm)?

My mentor gave me a "homework" to use 'sequence' to find the total number of working days, but I seem can't find it. I also not sure if 'sequence' is an actual syntax to use or just a keyword to search online.

In summary, need your guidance to find the following:

- find the total working days spend without using date_diff
- find the total working hours
- how to incorporate the public holidays

I have my coding as follow:

```
(DATE_DIFF('hour', start_date, end_date) - (DATE_DIFF('week',start_date, end_date)*2 * 24) - ((CASE WHEN DAY_OF_WEEK(start_date) > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 24) - ((CASE WHEN DAY_OF_WEEK(end_date) > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 24)) / 24.0 AS workday_spent
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you will need to do this over a stored procedure and a table of public holidays to loop over and also defining working hours

Answer (score 0):

Search for `sequence` here: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html

Here's the query which worked for me:

```sql
select count(*) as working_days, count(*)*8 as working_hours
from unnest(sequence(start_date, end_date)) t(d) 
where day_of_week(d) not in (6, 7);
```

And with public holidays:

```sql
select count(*) as working_days, count(*)*8 as working_hours
from unnest(sequence(start_date, end_date)) t(d) 
where day_of_week(d) not in (6, 7);
  and d not in (select d from public_holidays);
```

The query in action:

```
presto> select count(*) from unnest(sequence(cast('2020-01-01' as date), cast('2020-12-31' as date))) t(d) where day_of_week(d) not in (6, 7);
 _col0
-------
   262
(1 row)
```